# Converse, inverse and contrapositive statements of $p \to q$

Tags: propositional-calculus, boolean-algebra

Greetings fellow denizens of Planet Earth. I have a question in regards to propositional logic. My question is in regards to the to one making a statement. I'm going to use 2 random variables p and q.

Let's assume that p = "She is my heart"
Let's assume that q = "She is my wife"

Ok, now let's assume that the propositional statement is p -> q. Thus the output would resemble something like "If she is my heart, then she is my wife."

My main question is, is there ever a time in which the converse, inverse or contrapositive statement are logically equal to the propositional statement? Thanks!

Comment: The inverse is true, but I don't think the converse or contrapositive are true.

Answer (score 0):

I made a truth table and was able to find that the contrapositive equals the propositional statement from a logical point of view. Thanks for the help guys!